# How to find all of the service instance id provisioned from the specific service id in Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud

How can I get the full list of the service instance id that were provisioned from the service id that I registered in Bluemix?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Bluemix (Cloud Foundry) defines two ways to add your own services: User-Provided Services and Managed Services ([documentation](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/)).

User-Provided are added directly to your space, so you know the number of times you use it checking the space.

Managed Service are added to the catalog and they require the implementation of a piece of code called Service Broker. Just add a counter in it to know how many instances have been provisioned from potential users/spaces.